# Alphabetically ordering text that includes emoji

Tags: php, mysql, emoji, alphabetical

mySQL db query that returns user names. These names often include emoji which throws the order off completely. How to disregard the emoji in the ordering?

```
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `accounts`")
```

Comment: I would add all the results to an array, clear them from the array and then sort that, and then loop through that array and display the data.

Comment: Wouldn't that remove the emoji from the result. And how would you detect and remove the emoji?

Comment: It could. You could make 2 arrays with the same keys so you can pull the name with the emoji's from a sorted list without them. How do the emoji's look in the database? It should be some type of plaintext I assume

Comment: What order should ,  and  appear in?

Comment: ðŸ‡ºðŸ‡¸_SERBIA_ðŸ‡·ðŸ‡¸   in varchar field is (flag) SERBIA (flag)

Comment: Seems like quite a hassle and process power to link to arrays one with original and one with emoji stripped out. Then to rebuild each one over and over to reorder it to alphabetical